# How to select all rows with a unique field, and get all fields in that row in the result set in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table say something like this:

```
column_a  column_b
   foo        1
   bar        1
   baz        2
```

I need to get this in my result set:

```
    foo 1
    baz 2
```

Thus, I need to select rows where the field column_b is distinct. I tried coming up with ways to do this by using a subquery with select distinct but no dice. I'm still kind of noobish at SQL.

Comment: On which criteria should you get `foo,1` instead of `bar,1`?

Comment: Why are you excluding `bar`? If it's because `foo` "precedes" it, how do you define precedence? Using table order isn't a good idea, because it isn't well-defined.

Comment: Good point, I'm actually doing an order by date and would like to take the foo over the bar if foo is a more recent date than bar.

Comment: Yeah I should have written a more well defined question, I'm really looking for hints rather than a full answer

Comment: After examining my data further I realized that my solution was the wrong one.

:( Thanks to everyone who helped.

That is, I ended up solving it another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the following (using a datetime field, further to comments above):

```
SELECT   (
            SELECT   column_a 
            FROM     foo_table f2 
            WHERE    f2.column_b = f1.column_b 
            ORDER BY f2.date DESC
            LIMIT    1
         ) column_a,
         f1.column_b
FROM     foo_table f1
GROUP BY f1.column_b;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_table (column_a varchar(10), column_b int, date datetime);

INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES ('foo', 1, '2010-06-03 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES ('bar', 1, '2010-06-02 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO foo_table VALUES ('baz', 2, '2010-06-01 00:00:00');
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+
| column_a | column_b |
+----------+----------+
| foo      |        1 |
| baz      |        2 |
+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it - does it matter which column_a you get for each distinct value of column_b?

```
select column_a,column_b from yourtable group by column_b
```